# Send correct current time after a retry RxJava and Retrofit

Tags: android, rx-java, observable, retrofit2

I'm trying to send to the server the current time at the time the connection is established. I already know that this time may have some latency, regarding the health of the network. 
For this, I'm using retrofit(2) and rxjava(1), and I have some delay between retries and a retry count, something like this:

```
 mRetrofit = new ApiClient().getObservableClient();
 mService = mRetrofit.create(ApiObservableService.class);

 mService.sendServerTimeNow(getCurrentTime())
          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
          .retryWhen(«new RetryWithDelay(retries, delay))
          .subscribe(new CustomSubscriber<ResponseBody>());
```

My problem is, every time the retry is made, the getCurrentTime() is not refreshed and its value is always the same on the time of subscription.

```
E.g. 
 Retry 1 - 1482399029862
 Retry 2 - 1482399029862  //here should be changed to the new current time
 Retry 3 - 1482399029862  //here should be changed to the new current time
```

I had the felling that retry would re-subscribe, and if this is true is not suppose to refresh the current time?

This is my getCurrentTime()

```
public long getCurrentTime(){
  return System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

How can I accomplish this refresh of current time?

Additionally, I already tried but with no success:

```
Observable.just(getCurrentTime())
       .flatMap(new Func1<Long, Observable<ResponseBody>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<ResponseBody> call(Long aLong) {
               mService.sendServerTimeNow(aLong)
            }
        })
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .retryWhen(«new RetryWithDelay(retries, delay))
        .subscribe(new CustomSubscriber<ResponseBody>());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first understand that `Observable.just(getCurrentTime())` executes `getCurrentTime()` when the `Observable` sequence is assembled and doesn't make the call "magically" deferred:

```
final long now = getCurrentTime();

Observable<Long> o = Observable.just(now);

o.test().assertResult(now); // "now" is set in stone inside the Observable
o.test().assertResult(now);
o.test().assertResult(now);
```

You can instead have `Observable.fromCallable(() -> getCurrentTime())` which will only call `getCurrentTime` for each incoming subscriber, including the one by `retry`.

Comment: I did not knew the difference between just and fromCallable, thank you for the explication. It works thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at your example with `Observable.just` :

```
Observable.just(getCurrentTime())
          .flatMap(...)
          ...
```

can be rewritten as follow :

```
Long time = getCurrentTime()
Observable.just(time)
          .flatMap(...)
          ...
```

A `retry` will subscribe again to your `Observable` and will reuse the value of time.

To compute the value again, you'll have to compute the time again, using `Observable.fromCallable` for example

```
Observable.fromCallable(() -> getCurrentTime())
          .flatMap(...)
          ...
```